# How to get the hierarchy of particular employee using JPA spring boot?

Tags: mysql, java, hierarchy, recursive, self-join

I am trying to find a way to get the employee hierarchy in an organization using JPA and Spring boot.

The problem is similar to the following link
[Similar Data Model](https://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-self-join-annotations-one-to-many-mapping/)

If A reports to B and B reports to C and C reports to D,

For employee B i need the output to be B->C->D.

The following the Recursive query in Mysql

```
WITH RECURSIVE Employee_path(id,Name,bid) AS(
SELECT id,Name,bid
FROM Employee
WHERE id = 1005
UNION ALL
SELECT e.id,e.Name,e.bid
FROM Employee_path AS cp JOIN Employee AS e
ON cp.bid = e.id
)
SELECT * FROM Employee_path ORDER by bid ASC;
```

Since I am new to JPA I am unable to get the solution(I am not getting how to approach this problem)